# How do I connect a Razor Pages ASP.NET app to an already existing, not local MSSQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I want to create a Razor Pages app where I would display the entries from a database. What am I supposed to put in the Connection String? I have the login to this database and the server.

And after I connect to it, how do I access it and simply display all the rows from the db in a page?

Comment: There are a few things to consider with respect to the architecture of the database, but your connection string can be found in the `appsettings.json`. If you have access to the remote database (e.g. via the SQL Server Object Explorer) you can get the connection string of the database and copy it into the `DefaultConnection` field in your `appsettings.json`

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ . And you are asking two questions. Please ask one per question. And google this, because many have already asked this.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you should consider in order to access entities from DB in Razor Pages.

1. Set the Connection String in appsettings.json

local:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=XXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

remote:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;Database=XXXXXXX;User Id=yourUsername;password=yourPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  }
```

2. Add DB Context class that inherits DBContext ex. "YourDBContext"

```
public class YourDBContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

3. Add DbContext to app services

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<YourDBContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

Than you can use Dependency Injection and access entity in your page via context:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        YourDBContext_context;

        public IndexModel(YourDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            IList<Blog> entities = await _context.Blogs.ToListAsync();
  ....
```